# Login required for django Flatpages

Tags: django, django-flatpages, django-login, login-required

Is there an easy way to put login required decorator to all my Flatpages? 
Do I need to modify my url conf?

```
   (r'',include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),
```

Thanks,
Fred

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Django FlatPage model has a `registration_required` Boolean field. Set this to True to only allow logged-in users to view the page.

https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/flatpages/models.py

```
class FlatPage(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(_('URL'), max_length=100, db_index=True)
    title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField(_('content'), blank=True)
    enable_comments = models.BooleanField(_('enable comments'))
    template_name = models.CharField(_('template name'), max_length=70, blank=True,
        help_text=_("Example: 'flatpages/contact_page.html'. If this isn't provided, the system will use 'flatpages/default.html'."))
    registration_required = models.BooleanField(_('registration required'), help_text=_("If this is checked, only logged-in users will be able to view the page."))
    sites = models.ManyToManyField(Site)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'django_flatpage'
        verbose_name = _('flat page')
        verbose_name_plural = _('flat pages')
        ordering = ('url',)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s -- %s" % (self.url, self.title)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return self.url
```

Alternatively, you could just add the following to your flatpage template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>{{ flatpage.title }}</title>
</head>
<body>
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {{ flatpage.content }}
{% else %}
    Please <a href="">log in</a> to view this page.
{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```